# Change border-bottom and border-top color on refresh

Tags: javascript, css, colors

I would like to change the border-bottom and border-top of a page i'm working on.

This is my CSS:

```
.section-title {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
border-top:1px solid #000;
}
```

And this is my script:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
  $('section-title').each(function() {
     var col = 'rgb('+ (Math.floor(Math.random()*256)) +',' + (Math.floor(Math.random()*256)) + ','+(Math.floor(Math.random()*256))+')';
     $(this).css('color', col);
    }); });
```

What am i doing wrong, or what should i do to make this work? To get an idea ; http://www.mirlaklijn.nl/wp-new this is the website. the two 1 pixel borders above and below the title are what i would like to change randomly like the links do.

Many many thanks been thinking and trying for hours!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `border-color`:

```
$(this).css('border-color', col);
```

---

**P.S.** No need to run your own `each` loop. Let jQuery do it for you, by supplying a callback to `css`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.section-title').css('border-color', function() {
        return 'rgb(' +
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ',' + 
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ',' + 
            Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ',' +
        ')';
    });
});
```

Comment: yes worked like a charm! thank you so much ! this got me wondering, i tried adding border-bottom instead of border-color but that somehow doesn't work. is it possible to have the border-bottom and border-top 2 different colors too?

Comment: @user1084321 - well of course. Set the `border-top-color` and the `border-bottom-color` separately.

Comment: ohhhh i have to add -color to the end.. why didn't i come up with this!! thank you again so so much you have no idea haha!

Answer (score 0):

It's not `"color"` attribute that changes the border color. It's `"border-color"`. `"color"` attribute purpose is to change the text color (foreground color) only.

```
$(this).css('border-color', col);
```

Cheers